# directive appearing as literal text in rendered document

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, sections, autodoc

I want to display the docstrings for two functions, in between a couple of section headers, as follows:

```
===
API
===

.. autofunction:: parsons.aws.distribute_task

.. autofunction:: parsons.aws.event_command

***
S3
***
```

Both of the docstrings are appearing in the rendered HTML, but the second function also shows the Sphinx directive `.. autofunction:: parsons.aws.event_command` as text below the docstring:

[image: Rendered HTML]

Any ideas as to why is this occurring and how can I get rid of it?

You can see the problem (and all the code for this project) at the top of this file on GitHub:

https://github.com/move-coop/parsons/blob/master/docs/aws.rst

And in the built version of the documentation:

https://move-coop.github.io/parsons/html/aws.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code on GitHub doesn't have a blank line separating the two `.. autofunction::` directives:

```
.. autofunction :: parsons.aws.distribute_task
.. autofunction :: parsons.aws.event_command
```

[reStructuredText rules for directives](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#directives)  states that:

> **Actions taken in response to directives and** the interpretation of text in the directive content block or ***subsequent text block(s) are directive-dependent**.

So looking at the *"Syntax diagram"*, and the *"three logical parts"* of a directive block:

```
There are three logical parts to the directive block:

    Directive arguments.
    Directive options.
    Directive content.
```

(...)

```
Syntax diagram:

+-------+-------------------------------+
| ".. " | directive type "::" directive |
+-------+ block                         |
        |                               |
        +-------------------------------+
```

To me it's not entirely clear if *"subsequent text block(s)"* (that will have a directive dependent behavior) applies to a directive immediately following another or only to the *"three logical parts of the directive block"*.

A directive counts as an [Explicit Markup Block](https://documentation-style-guide-sphinx.readthedocs.io) so the third rule implies a directive should end before an unindented line.

> An explicit markup block is a text block:
> (...)
>
> - which ends before an unindented line.

Notice there's no clear ending between the two `.. autofunction::` directives (both are unindented).
Further on it is stated:

> **Blank lines are required between explicit markup blocks** and other elements, but are optional between explicit markup blocks where unambiguous.

It is generally safer to have blank lines after directives, to prevent any **unspecified behavior** (in your case, having the directive render normally and also be included textually).

If you leave a blank line after the directives it should work as expected.

**EDIT:** There's [this old style guide](https://documentation-style-guide-sphinx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/style-guide.html#blank-lines) mentioning 2 blank lines should be placed before overlined sections. I can't explain why (maybe it's a GitHub or readthedocs local issue) but apparently it solved the problem.

Comment: The code on GitHub actually does not reflect what I am testing locally. I have specifically tried this, and it did not fix the problem.

Comment: Here is my current PR in which I implemented the change you suggested, but the rendered HTML has not changed at all. https://github.com/move-coop/parsons/pull/411/files#diff-4f9915a7633b28c69101a31702a1ae0fR75

Comment: Apologies for not clarifying this... since it made no difference in the HTML output, I figured this change was unimportant (but like you, my initial reaction was to think the missing blank line was causing the problem).

Comment: @Slowloris there's [this old style guide](https://documentation-style-guide-sphinx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/style-guide.html#blank-lines) recommending 2 blank lines before overline headers. It might render differently on github, readthedocs, and locally. Try adding a couple of blank lines before and after for `"good measure"`. If it doesn't work let us know and we'll think of something else.

Comment: @Slowloris I checked your [parsons.aws](https://github.com/move-coop/parsons/tree/master/parsons/aws) package. I honestly haven't tried this kind of layout, you include directives (`.. code-block::`) inside the docstrings, I always keep that in the `.rst` files. It's also not standard google-style to put backticks around the `Args` docstring section. Also, the types are normally expressed in parenthesis before the colon, like `bucket (str): text` instead of `bucket: str \n text`. Otherwise I couldn't find anything wrong with your code. But the blank lines between directives is still advisable.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking a look. I'm just trying to be consistent with the existing style in this library - I'm not a maintainer, just a volunteer contributor!

Comment: Actually, adding one more blank line after the `autofunction` line solved the problem! If you want to update your answer to focus on the 2 blank lines before headers, I will accept it.

Comment: I'm aware, I'm a long time SO user, just was taking time to respond to your question above :)

Comment: I believe I fixed the `.. autoclass :: parsons.S3` issue in my PR already: https://github.com/move-coop/parsons/pull/411/files#diff-4f9915a7633b28c69101a31702a1ae0fR138

Comment: Seems like it also needed an extra blank line before the header